# Error when trying to sum two products, where one product is a 1x2 matrix

Tags: matrix, maple

First question that I've posted here, I'm working on some code for my final on Monday and for some reason I keep getting the following error. Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated. Thanks!;

[The following imagine shows the error in my code, I had switched to 1D math and still can't seem to find the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2tK3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maple the global name `D` has a preassigned value. It is the differential operator. For example,

```
f := t -> sec(t):

D(f);

      t -> sec(t)*tan(t)
```

The global name `D` is also *protected*, ie. you cannot assign another values to it.

And in general it is not a good idea to use the name `D` like a dummy variable in your code (since is has already been assigned a system procedure, by default). Your example is an (unfortunate) example of strangeness that could ensue.

```
D * Vector([-3,1]);
  Error, (in LinearAlgebra:-Multiply) invalid arguments
```

You have a couple of alternatives:

1) Use another name instead, such as `DD`.

2) If you Maple version is recent then you could declare it (once) as a local name for top-level use. For example,

```
restart;

local D;

               D

D * Vector([-3,1]);

             [-3 D]
             [    ]
             [ D  ]
```

If you do declare local `D` for top-level use then you can still utilize the differential operator by its global name `:-D`. Eg.

```
restart;
local D:

f := t -> sec(t):

D(f);     # does nothing, since this is the local D

             D(f)

:-D(f);

       t -> sec(t)*tan(t)
```

If all that sounds confusing, you'll probably be better off just using another name instead.

The are only a few short symbols with preassigned values or uses, eg. `Pi`, `I`, `D`.

You might want to also have a look at the Help page for Topics [initialconstants](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=initialconstants&term=initialconstants) and [trydeclaringlocal](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=trydeclaringlocal&term=trydeclaringlocal) .

Comment: Oh wow, I ran into that issue before I believe with another protected variable, never would have thought of that. It works now, thank you so much! Is there anywhere I could find a list of these protected variables?

Comment: nvm, I just read the end of your comment regarding other preassigned values. All good, thanks again!